# Python call class with inputs from list

Tags: python, list

I have a class called Interval for which I want to create multiple interval objects from a list of intervals. How do I do it with map ?

```
class Interval(object):
    def __init__(self, s=0, e=0):
        self.start = s
        self.end = e

intervals = [[1,2],[3,5],[6,7],[8,10],[12,16]]
```

I tried to do:

```
objs = map(Interval, intervals)
```

But this sends the full interval as the first parameter rather than the inputs to the class individually.

Comment: objs = list(map(Interval, intervals)) should work

Comment: @AlanLeuthard: it works, but then `s` will get a list as input, and `e` will be `0` for all cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import starmap

objs = starmap(Interval,intervals)
```

Mind that `starmap` works lazily (like `map` in Python-3.x) and that you will need to materialize it, for instance using `list(..)`:

```
>>> list(objs)
[<__main__.Interval object at 0x7efbf7e82358>, <__main__.Interval object at 0x7efbf7e82390>, <__main__.Interval object at 0x7efbf7e823c8>, <__main__.Interval object at 0x7efbf7e82400>, <__main__.Interval object at 0x7efbf7e82438>]
```

If you do not want to use the `itertools` library, an equivalent is:

```
objs = map(lambda x: Interval(*x),intervals)
```

As far as I know, that's why they call it *star*map: because of the asterisk if you would use a lambda expression.

Comment: Are you everywhere at this time of the night? hahaha, and also better answer... I must admit

Comment: Ah! starmap, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
>>> objs = []
>>> for interval in intervals:
...     objs.append(Interval(*interval))
... 
>>> objs
[<__main__.Interval object at 0x013E67D0>, <__main__.Interval object at 0x013E6910>, <__main__.Interval object at 0x013E68F0>, <__main__.Interval object at 0x013E6870>, <__main__.Interval object at 0x013E6950>]
>>> objs[0]
<__main__.Interval object at 0x013E67D0>
>>> objs[0].start
1
>>> objs[0].end
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try also the old-school way:

```
class Interval(object):
    def __init__(self, s=0, e=0):
        self.start = s
        self.end = e


def map_intervals(intervals):
        ret = []
        for inter in intervals:
          ret.append(Interval(inter[0],inter[1]))
        return ret
inters = [[1,2],[3,5],[6,7],[8,10],[12,16]]
```